# Pandas Объединение таблиц

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть две таблицы

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Км':['Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan',1,'Nan','Nan',2],
                'От ПК_л':[0,100,200,300,'Nan',1000,1100,'Nan'],
               'До ПК_л':[100,200,300,400,'Nan',1100,1200,'Nan'],
                'V1_л': [10,20,30,40,100,10,20,30],
                'V2_л': [1,2,3,4,10,1,2,3]
               })


Км  От ПК_л   До ПК_л  V1_л  V2_л
Nan     0       100     10     1
Nan     100     200     20     2
Nan     200     300     30     3
Nan     300     400     40     4
1       Nan     Nan     100    10
Nan     1000    1100    10     1
Nan     1100    1200    20     2
2       Nan     Nan     30     3 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Км':['Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan',1,'Nan',2],
                    'От ПК_п':[0,100,200,300,400,500,'Nan',1300,'Nan'],
                   'До ПК_п':[100,200,300,400,500,600,'Nan',1400,'Nan'],
                    'V1_п': [10,20,30,40,50,40,200,10,10],
                    'V2_п': [1,2,3,4,1,1,12,2,2]
                   })
Км  От ПК_п   До ПК_п  V1_п     V2_п
Nan     0       100     10       1
Nan     100     200     20       2
Nan     200     300     30       3
Nan     300     400     40       4
Nan     400     500     50       1
Nan     500     600     40       1
1       Nan     Nan     200     12
Nan     1300    1400    10       2
2        Nan    Nan     10       2
```

По итогу нужно получить таблицу в которой строка км будет выравниваться для обеих таблиц, а недостающие клетки заполняются значениями Nan. В строчках 1, 2 потом вписывается сумма строк.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Км':['Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan',1,'Nan','Nan',2],
                    'От ПК_л':[0,100,200,300,'Nan','Nan','Nan',1000,1100,'Nan'],
                   'До ПК_л':[100,200,300,400,'Nan','Nan','Nan',1100,1200,'Nan'],
                    'V1_л': [10,20,30,40,'Nan','Nan',100,10,20,30],
                    'V2_л': [1,2,3,4,'Nan','Nan',10,1,2,3],
                    'От ПК_п':[0,100,200,300,400,500,'Nan',1300,'Nan','Nan'],
                   'До ПК_п':[100,200,300,400,500,600,'Nan',1400,'Nan','Nan'],
                    'V1_п': [10,20,30,40,50,40,200,10,'Nan',10],
                    'V2_п': [1,2,3,4,1,1,12,2,'Nan',2]
                     }) 
    Км  От ПК_л     До ПК_л     V1_л    V2_л    От ПК_п     До ПК_п     V1_п V2_п
    Nan       0     100     10      1       0       100     10        1
    Nan     100     200     20      2       100     200     20        2
    Nan     200     300     30      3       200     300     30        3
    Nan     300     400     40      4       300     400     40        4
    Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     400     500     50        1
    Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan     500     600     40        1
    1       Nan     Nan     100     10      Nan     Nan     200       12
    Nan     1000    1100    10      1       1300    1400    10        2
    Nan     1100    1200    20      2       Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan
    2       Nan     Nan     30      3       Nan     Nan     10        2
```

Пробовал `pd.merge(df1,df2, on='КМ', how = 'outer')` таблица получается в 4000 строк притом что исходные таблицы длинной в 200 строк, как я понимаю потому что происходит сопоставление по Nan.
   Также пробовал pd.concat(), результат уже лучше но всеравно не получается,pd.join() тоже не принесло результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать `merge` по индексу:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Км':['Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan',1,'Nan','Nan',2],
                'От ПК_л':[0,100,200,300,'Nan',1000,1100,'Nan'],
               'До ПК_л':[100,200,300,400,'Nan',1100,1200,'Nan'],
                'V1_л': [10,20,30,40,100,10,20,30],
                'V2_л': [1,2,3,4,10,1,2,3]
               })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Км':['Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan',1,'Nan',2],
                    'От ПК_п':[0,100,200,300,400,500,'Nan',1300,'Nan'],
                   'До ПК_п':[100,200,300,400,500,600,'Nan',1400,'Nan'],
                    'V1_п': [10,20,30,40,50,40,200,10,10],
                    'V2_п': [1,2,3,4,1,1,12,2,2]})


df1=df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Получим df1:

```
  Км_x От ПК_л До ПК_л   V1_л  V2_л Км_y От ПК_п До ПК_п  V1_п  V2_п
0  Nan       0     100   10.0   1.0  Nan       0     100    10     1
1  Nan     100     200   20.0   2.0  Nan     100     200    20     2
2  Nan     200     300   30.0   3.0  Nan     200     300    30     3
3  Nan     300     400   40.0   4.0  Nan     300     400    40     4
4    1     Nan     Nan  100.0  10.0  Nan     400     500    50     1
5  Nan    1000    1100   10.0   1.0  Nan     500     600    40     1
6  Nan    1100    1200   20.0   2.0    1     Nan     Nan   200    12
7    2     Nan     Nan   30.0   3.0  Nan    1300    1400    10     2
8  NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN    2     Nan     Nan    10     2
```

Не совсем понятно из вопроса, куда какую сумму нужно занести - если вам нужно просто "сложить" километры из обеих таблиц, то поступить можно проще.. Но не забывайте, что у вас Nan - не настоящий, а строковый, поэтому нужно сделать пару преобразований:

```
df1 =df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df2 =df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df1 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

что даст нам следующий датасет  df1 (обратите внимание на колонку "Км"):

```
    V1_л   V1_п  V2_л  V2_п  До ПК_л  До ПК_п   Км  От ПК_л  От ПК_п
0   10.0   10.0   1.0   1.0    100.0    100.0  NaN      0.0      0.0
1   20.0   20.0   2.0   2.0    200.0    200.0  NaN    100.0    100.0
2   30.0   30.0   3.0   3.0    300.0    300.0  NaN    200.0    200.0
3   40.0   40.0   4.0   4.0    400.0    400.0  NaN    300.0    300.0
4  100.0   50.0  10.0   1.0      NaN    500.0  1.0      NaN    400.0
5   10.0   40.0   1.0   1.0   1100.0    600.0  NaN   1000.0    500.0
6   20.0  200.0   2.0  12.0   1200.0      NaN  1.0   1100.0      NaN
7   30.0   10.0   3.0   2.0      NaN   1400.0  2.0      NaN   1300.0
8    NaN   10.0   NaN   2.0      NaN      NaN  2.0      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Получается не то то нужно, данные из строки км1 в финальной таблице должны быть на одной строке одной строке, и та таблица в которой меньше строк должна заполняться nan пока строки с суммами выровняются друг относительно друга. Соответствено для км2 тоже самое но дополняться будет уже другая таблица. А по суммам, потом туда вбиваются екселевские формулы сложения по столбцам = сумм(a1:a10) и тд для каждого столбца

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Первый вариант решения через merge вас тоже не устраивает?

Comment: Да не устраивает, если объединять по индексам часть таблицы просто обрезается. Я написал что должно получиться(df3)